# Restrict access to global context with javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following function

```
function foo(){
    console.log(test);
    console.log(window);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent **foo** to access the window object ? I've tried the following

```
foo.apply({});
```

But it only changes the **this** and leaves access to **window**

Comment: Why would you need such a thing ?

Comment: The function's scope is (nearly) always a descendant of the global scope, you hardly can restrict that (and it would make the script no longer work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var window = {};` to override the reference to the global object. You can additionally use the `.apply({})` method to prevent access via `this`.

However, nothing you can do will stop undeclared variables from being get/set on the global object, short of manually defining every possible variable name...

As Bergi points out, `window = (function() {return this;}());` will restore the reference to the `window` object. This is again something that probably cannot be stopped.

Comment: And how would you prevent anyone from restoring the reference, e.g. by `window = (function(){return this;}());` (or `eval` magic if in strict mode)?

Comment: @Bergi Huh, that's a good one. Didn't occur to me XD But since my answer is basically saying "you can make it difficult, but there are ways", the point is the same.

Comment: `(function(){return this;}())` will not work in strict mode.